# Line spacing after chapter and sections

Tags: line-spacing

I want to increase the line spacing to 1.5 (I exaggerated in the code below to 5 space). However the space between the sections and the text also increase, I dont want them to change. How can prevent this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=4.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\fontsize{12}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{0.3em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{12}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.3em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\fontsize{12}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{0.3em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\fontsize{12}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{0.3em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{30pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{6pt}{6pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{6pt}{6pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

\setstretch{5} % I exaggerated this!

\begin{document}

\chapter{CHAPTER NAME}

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortisfacilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales.

\section{SECTION NAME}

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortisfacilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales.

\subsection{SUBSECTION NAME}

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortisfacilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales.

\subsubsection{SUBSUBSECTION NMAE}

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortisfacilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not a good solution, but you could calculate the necessary spacing for `\titlespacing` based on the `\setstretch`-value.

Comment: @Skillmon thank you but that's not what I want.

Comment: @Skillmon thank you but that's not what I want.

Comment: why isn't that what you want, isn't that _exactly_ what you want? Any solution is going to be effectively that, the only difference would be whether the calculations are done by the macros.